# Deploying an Angular 2 + Express App with Network Solutions

Tags: angular, express, web-hosting

I am struggling to deploy an application. I have a static storage bucket with Network Solutions (networksoultions.com) that is currently hosting my website. However, I've added an Express backend to send the contents of a form as an email and have no idea how to get the express server to run on the storage service.

Right now there is an "htdocs" folder and it will render whatever is contained in the index.html file. That works great for my Angular 2 app, but how do I also get the backend to run?

I would use an EC2 node with AWS, but my employer wants the site to remain on the Network Solutions account. Do they have an equivalent to EC2? Can I somehow start the server on the storage service? Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You should really ask that from Network Solutions. What you need is a server you fully control, VM or a microservice platform like Lambda to run NodeJS on.

Comment: If you only need simple form to email though, google for free email sending APIs. There are some that are free up to a considerably large amount of emails and cheap up from that.

Comment: hi, how are you?... can you tell me how to deply an angular project on network solutions host?

Comment: @samuelleonardoPerezGaitan If you have a question it would be best to post it as a question instead of a comment on an existing question. If you create a new question and tag me in a comment I'll put the answer there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked with Network Solutions. According to the representative I communicated with they do not offer services that support Node backends.

Express requires a server (as @funkizer stated) so it looks like I'll have to use AWS after all.